# ViewModel method appears to not be working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, class, viewmodel

I am trying to create a page that consists of a list of items. A dialog box appears on the screen to take the input for the item that has to be added in the list. The input element is a TextFormField. To address the issue of field being empty, I have created a fieldValidator method in a viewModel. But when I test the empty field, it doesn't seem to be working. Any Inisghts onto this issue would be very much appreciated.

This is the UI code for the ListView.

```
         Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                    child: skills.isEmpty
                        ? const SizedBox()
                        : ListView.builder(
                            itemBuilder: (context, count) {
                              return Container(
                                height: 80,
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 30, 30, 1),
                                ),
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 20,
                                  ),
                                  child: Stack(
                                    children: [
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        child: Text(
                                          skills[count],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                        child: InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              skills.removeAt(count);
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: const Icon(
                                            FontAwesomeIcons.trash,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            itemCount: skills.length,
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            displayDialog(context, widget.skillMod, textDialog, skills, 
                              () {
                              setState(() {
                                var skill = textDialog.value.text;
                                skills.add(skill);
                              });
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 20,
                              vertical: 20,
                            ),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: const Text(
                              'Add Skill',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

This is the code for the dialog box with the text field that appears when 'Add Skill' button is clicked.

```
Future<void> displayDialog(BuildContext context, SkillModel skillMod, TextEditingController tCont, List<String?> skills, Function() ontap) async {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        content: TextFormField(
          controller: tCont,
          validator: skillMod.fieldValidator,
          scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Add Skill",
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 3,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.symmetric(
                horizontal: 40,
                vertical: 10,
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
              child: const Text(
                'Cancel',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              if (tCont.value.text.isNotEmpty) {
                ontap();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.symmetric(
                horizontal: 40,
                vertical: 10,
              ),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
              child: const Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

This is the code for my viewModel file, that contains the Validator method.

```
class SkillModel {
  final String? skill;

  SkillModel(this.skill);

  factory SkillModel.newUser() {
    return SkillModel(null);
  }

  String? fieldValidator(String? s) {
    if (s!.isEmpty) {
      return 'Field is required.';
    }
  }

  SkillModel updateSM({
    final String? skill,
  }) {
    return SkillModel(skill ?? this.skill);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    // TODO: implement toString
    return 'SkillModel($skill)';
  }
}
```

This is where I initialize the main screen which contains the listview.

```
        InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SkillsUI(
                        skillMod: SkillModel.newUser(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
```

Thank You.

Comment: You read manual how validate form? https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation